# Auth.currentuser being overwritten by newest login (across all different sessions and browsers)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase.currentUser is not working for me.
For example, let's say I have two different users on two completely different wifis and computers. If user A logs in, user B is automatically logged in to user A's account when they access the website. If user B logs out and logs in to their account, user A is logged into user B's account.

Firebase Version: **8.2.3**

I want to fetch each user's data separately with auth.currentUser.

Here is my code for that

```js
const currentUser = auth.currentUser
```

The last login's user is fetched with this, even if the user logged into their own account.

Here is how I initialize firebase and export variables.

```js
let app;
if(firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    app =firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
    app = firebase.app();
}
const auth = firebase.auth()
const db = firebase.firestore();
module.exports =  {auth, db}
```

Here is how I log users in

```js
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      console.log(userCredential)
      res.redirect('/')
      console.log(`logged in`)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      return res.render('login', { error: errorMessage, state: state })

    });
```

I am not sure why this is happening as auth.currentUser works fine for all others, but please let me know if anyone finds anything wrong with this code.

Comment: Where does this code run? You've tagged this [tag:node.js]

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: It means exactly what it means. Does this code run in the browser or in Node?

Comment: It runs in the terminal with node

Comment: Are you sure about that? I don't really understand how that's possible (I thought you had to use the Firebase Admin SDK to run code server-side) but that would explain why your users are sharing sessions if they've been created on the server

Comment: Oh that is interesting I'll check it out